# How to build objects that avoid a ActiveRecord::HasManyThroughCantAssociateThroughHasOneOrManyReflection erros in rails?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, activerecord

I am experiencing the `ActiveRecord::HasManyThroughCantAssociateThroughHasOneOrManyReflection` error when trying to build a new object in my rails app. It does not fit any of the standard errors I've seen, and can't be fixed with `inverse_of` associations.

I presume I need to run a callback to help this work - can anyone help fix the issue below:

```
def PhoneNumber do
 belongs_to :key_contact
end

def KeyContact do
 has_many :phone_numbers
 has_many :sale_contacts
end

def SaleContact do
 belongs_to :key_contact
 belongs_to :sales_opportunity
 has_many :phone_numbers, through: :key_contact
 accepts_nested_attributes_for :phone_numbers
end
```

As you can see, SaleContact is the join table where key_contacts and sales_opportunities meet - basically I'm picking existing key_contacts and displaying them on a sales_opportunity page with some additional details (role, preference etc - I've excluded this for brevity).

When adding a new sale_contact I want to offer users the ability to also add phone_numbers at the same time. This is throwing my activerecord error.

My SaleContact Controller:

```
def new
 @sale_contact = SaleContact.new
 @phone_number = @sale_contact.phone_numbers.build
end
```

This works to show the fields_for phone_number on the input form, and passed the right attributes through the params hash for adding a new phone_number, but that's when I get the error:

`ActiveRecord::HasManyThroughCantAssociateThroughHasOneOrManyReflection (Cannot modify association 'SaleContact#phone_numbers' because the source reflection class 'PhoneNumber' is associated to 'KeyContact' via :has_many.):`

From what I can see:

1. My new controller action builds a phone_number, but because the sale_contact does not yet know which key_contact it's associated with I presume ActiveRecord gets confused
2. If I try and remove the @sale_contact.phone_number.build line (replacing it with PhoneNumber.new for example) the fields no longer appear on the SaleContact new form

As such I was thinking of creating a callback to strip out the phone_number_attributes from the sale_contact hash, destroy the newly built phone_number and all associations, then start fresh by passing the phone_numbers_attributes to a PhoneNumber.new(phone_number_attributes) action and saving as a separate transaction. Would that work?

Answer (score 0):

You could try this instead:

```
delegate :phone_numbers, to: :key_contact
```

Comment: Thanks Hoang - how would that work in the context I've included above? I looked at the delegate method yesterday but couldn't quite understand how to make it operational.

Comment: `has_many through` and `delegate` are for basically the same purpose, that is reducing the chain of calling by hiding the intermediate model.

However, `A has_many/has_one C through B` only works in case model A `has_many/has_one` model B, and B `belongs_to` model C.

Comment: And you are right, you must associate a key contact to sale_log first anyway. `has_many through` and `delegate` is only for hiding, not eliminating the intermediate associations.

Comment: Thanks Hoang. I managed to build one phone_number with a very convoluted method, but the sale_contact validations still failed (even though the phone_number persisted in the DB). I'll probably drop this nested form, as I can add phone_numbers easily on the model once a sale_contact is created, unless someone else can come up with a workaround that fits.